# How do I load the __all__ attributes of submodules?

Tags: python, python-import

I see code using this neat way of defining the `__all__` of a package:

```
from .submoduleA import *
from .submoduleB import *

# This relies on each of the submodules having an __all__ variable.
__all__ = (
    submoduleA.__all__ +
    submoduleB.__all__
)
```

e.g., [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py), in Python's stdlib.

I tried (on 3.10) and it works, but I don't understand why.
Should it not be raising name errors on each `submoduleX.__all__` (and indeed my linter thinks so, too)? Can someone please explain?

Comment: This is really neat. I've been jumping through hoops trying to do things like `from submoduleA import __all__ as _all; __all__.extend(_all); del _all`. This is so much nicer

Comment: Not positive, but I think it treats `subModuleA` the same as a top-level package as in `import foo.bar.baz`, which binds `foo` to the package even though it was not the "target" of the `import` statement. It's just a side effect of how `import` statements work.

Comment: Note that this works only in the `__init__.py`, i.e. in the "root" module of a package. It is just an effect of an `import`  as @chepner wrote. BTW, from another module you could use e.g. `sys.modules[__package__].submoduleA` - the first part `sys.modules[__package__]` gives you the "root" of the name hieratchy, i.e. the `__init__.py` module object.